# Javascript function doesnt work, simple code

Tags: javascript

Quite simple code below doesnt work. No idea why, JS function to move image smoothly.
Help would be great guys, tryed almost everything.

Code ready to copy paste to php script and test it. 
Many thanks in advance

```
<?php
echo "

<script type='text/javascript'>

var img = document.getElementById( 'test' );

function translate( elem, x, y ) {
    var left = 120,
        top = 120,
        dx = left - x,
        dy = top - y,
        i = 1,
        count = 20,
        delay = 20;

    function loop() {
        if ( i >= count ) { return; }
        i += 1;
        elem.style.left = ( left - ( dx * i / count ) ).toFixed( 0 ) + 'px';
        elem.style.top = ( top - ( dy * i / count ) ).toFixed( 0 ) + 'px';
        setTimeout( loop, delay );
    }

    loop();
}

</script>
";
echo '
</head>
<body>
  <img id="test" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="position:absolute; left:120px; top:120px;">


<a href="#" onclick="translate(\'test\', 30 , 30)">Translate to (0, 200)</a>

</body>
';
?>
```

Comment: Write javascript code outside from PHP

Comment: Why are you using echo to print out the html/js?  You can just close the php tag.

Comment: already tryed that, writing javascript outside php same result as here

Comment: Also, "doesn't work" is the most vague description.  What about it is not working?  You are seeing errors in your console, or the results are not expected?

Comment: problem is i dont know how to debug javascript, and i dont need to write javascript code often so i need little fix here and im done with JS ;)

Comment: im trying to make simplier and usable for me this working code http://fiddle.jshell.net/qEVVT/1/show/

Comment: Easy - the function sig for translate() says that you'll pass the element to be dealt with. Yet you set the &lt;a&gt; tag's onclick action to call the function, while specifying the element by it's text Id. No no no no! See solution in a moment or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function translate( elem, x, y ) {
    var left = 120,
        top = 120,
        dx = left - x,
        dy = top - y,
        i = 1,
        count = 20,
        delay = 20;

    function loop() 
    {
        if ( i >= count ) 
            return;
        i += 1;
        elem.style.left = ( left - ( dx * i / count ) ).toFixed( 0 ) + 'px';
        elem.style.top = ( top - ( dy * i / count ) ).toFixed( 0 ) + 'px';
        setTimeout( loop, delay );
    }
    loop();
}

window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false);

function myInit()
{
    byId('myAnchor').addEventListener('click', handleLinkClick, false);
}

function handleLinkClick(evt)
{
    //translate(byId('test'), 30, 30);  // only works on the #test target.
    translate(this, 30, 30);  // makes the handler work for any element it's attached to.
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="test" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" style="position:absolute; left:120px; top:120px;">
  <a id='myAnchor' href="#">Translate to (0, 200)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Man you are amazing :) working like charm. Im curious why u need to add this two functions?

Comment: there is one problem, you not using <a href="#">link</a> to move the image. That is crucial for this code. Easy fix?

Comment: got it :) add to <a onclick="handleLinkClick()" and comment out addEventListener('click', handleLinkClick, false);

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Sorry, I seem to have lost the id attribute from the anchor. I'll update the code in a second. I added the functions like this, because (a) you know which element triggered the event automatically if you use addEventListener (the `this` keyword in the function refers to the element that triggered the event) (b) Because you can add multiple event handlers to a single event on a single element. You can also remove single events.